# Can anyone identify this bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Spotted in Czech Republic. Our office was hit with cockroach infestation, so I'm afraid if I haven't carried one home.

[image]

Comment: Looks quite like a cockroach. Did you damage it somehow?

Comment: From my experiments with cockroaches as a kid (and crickets, mouses. frogs, ants, gecko's) this cilinder definately reminds me of their egg sac.
(English is not my primary language, forgive any mistakes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is German cockroach *([Blattella germanica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_cockroach))* with two dark parallel streaks on it's pronotum.

The one in your picture is a lady laying her ootheca.

[image]

It is a pest.

Here's it in different [stages](http://www.prevailpest.com/cockroaches_clip_image008.jpg) of life cycle.

Things you might like to know:

> Blattella germanica occurs widely in human buildings, but is particularly associated with restaurants, food processing facilities, hotels, and institutional establishments such as nursing homes.
>
> German cockroaches are omnivorous scavengers. They are attracted particularly to meats, starches, sugars, and fatty foods. Where a shortage of foodstuffs exists, they may eat household items such as soap, glue, and toothpaste.
>
> The German cockroach reproduces faster than any other residential cockroach, growing from egg to reproductive adult in approximately 50 – 60 days.

<sub>Source: Wikipedia and different pest service websites.</sub>

Comment: Finally found it!